# Async promise not awaited for before return statement

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, sendgrid

Had this problem yesterday, changed some code, and it's happening again... Why don't both mails send? The promise is not awaited for. Sometimes 1, sometimes 2 mails send. Bool "messagesSent" also returns false sometimes, when it should return true.

The function:

```
private async Task<bool> SendMails(string email, string name, string pdfPath, string imgPath)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(_config["SendGrid:Key"]);
    bool messagesSent = false;
    try
    {
        var messageClient = new SendGridMessage
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(_config["SendGrid:Recipient"]),
            Subject = "Subject1",
            HtmlContent = _textManager.Get("email-b")
        };

        var MessageServer = new SendGridMessage
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(_config["SendGrid:Recipient"]),
            Subject = "Subject2",
            HtmlContent = _textManager.Get("email-s")
        };

        messageClient.AddTo(email, name);
        MessageServer.AddTo(email, name);

        string[] fileListClient = new string[] { pdfPath };
        string[] FileListServer = new string[] { pdfPath, imgPath };

        foreach (var file in fileListClient)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                await messageClient.AddAttachmentAsync(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.OpenRead());
        }

        foreach (var file in FileListServer)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                await MessageServer.AddAttachmentAsync(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.OpenRead());
        }

        var responseClient = await client.SendEmailAsync(messageClient);
        var responseServer = await client.SendEmailAsync(MessageServer);

        if (responseClient.StatusCode.ToString() == "202" && responseServer.StatusCode.ToString() == "202")
        {
            messagesSent = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    return messagesSent;
}
```

Called by:

```
                bool sentMails = await SendMails(formCollection["email"], formCollection["name"], pdfPath, imgPath);

                if (!sentMails)
                {
                    errorMessage = "Error sending mails.";
                    succes = false;
                }
```

**EDIT:**
Request was valid, the call was being blocked by ISP/MailServer. This had nothing to do with faulty async.

Comment: Side note: Keep in mind that some mail clients, like the windows smtp service that runs on IIS will place the mail in a directory and then send it right after. You can also configure it for directory drop only. Calling the SendMail in c# only delivers it to that process and the actual sending and send schedule is nondetermenistic.

Comment: If you get no exception, it seems quite likely that sending fails somehow. Note that you do not do anything with the `response` variables other than checking them for particular values, so if no exception occurs but a status other than "202" is returned you simply won't see what went wrong. The use of `async` / `await` itself doesn't appear to be the problem here.

Comment: You could use `Task.WhenAll()` to ensure that both processes have finished before moving on.

Comment: @JeroenMostert When I log everything, they both return a 202 (succesful) but still nothing sends.

Comment: If you're seeing results, then the claim in the first paragraph that "The promise is not awaited for" doesn't seem to be right. It sounds like this code is correctly waiting for the mail server to respond, and it's responding with a 202 in both cases. (As an aside, you're currently sending one email at a time - you could call `SendEmailAsync` both times, *then* await the returned tasks.) As others have said, there's no indication that async/await is causing a problem here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, problem seemed to be in the SendGrid API. The request is valid, but it's being blocked by the ISP/MailServer.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the whole point of an asynchroneous call, is not to "wait" or delay performance. The method will just 'run'. Unless there is an exception raised in that method, there is nothing that would prevent the method from not get executed successfully.

Try adding a break-point and see why the messagesSent returns false sometimes, I am suspecting this line:

```
if (responseClient.StatusCode.ToString() == "202" && responseServer.StatusCode.ToString() == "202")
```

Is there any chance that the StatusCode might be returning a "200" as well?